# Minimo.CAB For WinCE Core

Tags: mobile, browser, windows-ce, fennec

I am looking for a Browser for Windows CE Core 5 OS, I could find the Suitable Browser is Minimo 0.016 (cab file for instillation) but I cannot file a Instillation file. Please Help.

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

Try Wceload Tool, you can find info here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms933760.aspx